# Can't upgrade old Ubuntu, error processing package fontconfig

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, do-release-upgrade

I'm running old Ubuntu **Server** 13.04 (raring), and trying to upgrade or even install any packages I'm getting the following error:

```
root@oem-mobilidade:~# sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 0 não atualizados.
1 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
Depois desta operação, 0 B adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Configurando fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 fontconfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)




root@oem-mobilidade:~# cat /var/log/fontconfig.log
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 21 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/.local/share/fonts: fc-cache: symbol lookup error: fc-cache: undefined symbol: FcStrListFirst
```

PS: Sorry for the portuguese output.

I read some articles telling to purge **fontconfig** package and reinstalling it, but I'm afraid of doing this because of this:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ca-certificates-java* cacti* cacti-spine* default-jre-headless* fontconfig* fontconfig-config* icedtea-7-jre-jamvm* libcairo2* libfontconfig1* libgd2-xpm* libpango1.0-0*
  librrd4* libxft2* openjdk-7-jre-headless* php5-gd* rrdtool* tomcat7* tomcat7-admin* tomcat7-common* tomcat7-docs* tomcat7-examples*
```

This server runs several applications, like Cacti, and other web based tools that depends on apache, tomcat, php, etc, so I'm worried about removing those packages above.

Please, help!!!

Comment: You should be more worried about using a vulnerable, unsupported, with no security updates OS for over a whole year now.

Comment: I agree, but I need to get it to work first, then upgrade OS.

Comment: What is in "/var/log/fontconfig.log" ? 13.04 is beyond EOL so support is limited at best.

Comment: /usr/share/fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu: skipping, existing cache is valid: 21 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/root/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/root/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
fc-cache: symbol lookup error: fc-cache: undefined symbol: FcStrListFirst

Comment: **SOLVED!!!** Downloaded fontconfig.deb package from [DEB PACKAGE](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/2.10.1-0ubuntu3/+build/3735647/+files/fontconfig_2.10.1-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb)  and reinstalled with **dpkg -i fontconfig_2.10.1-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb**. Now apt-get is working fine and I can upgrade my OS. Thanks guys!!

Comment: Close voters: Issues upgrading Ubuntu are not off-topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!** Downloaded fontconfig.deb package from [DEB PACKAGE HERE](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/2.10.1-0ubuntu3/+build/3735647/+files/fontconfig_2.10.1-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb)  and reinstalled with

```
dpkg -i fontconfig_2.10.1-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Now apt-get is working fine and I can upgrade my OS. Thanks guys!!